# Boldify correct part of contact's name in iOS's AddressBook?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, addressbook, abaddressbook

I'm using AddressBook to get an array of all records, and then displaying the names in a UITableView.

My question is, how can I baldify the correct part of the full name, like in the Contacts app? I could create a huge number of if statements, but I was wondering if there's an easier way.

Here's how I'm retrieving the names:

```
_person = person;
CFStringRef name = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
NSString *nameString = CFBridgingRelease(name);

[self.textLabel setText:nameString];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use for example NSAttributedString (you may change every attribute for every part of string). Make your UILabel to use attributed string of course

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [NSMutableAttributedString attributedStringWithString:@"Hello World!"];
 // for those calls we don't specify a range so it affects the whole string
[attrStr setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12]];
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
// now we only change the color of "Hello"
[attrStr setTextColor:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
```